# Replace characters in row Mysql

Tags: mysql, replace

I have table in db.
Structure:

```
street_id | street_atrribute | street_name1 | street_name2
```

In this database I have row with ""
For example:

```
546  | ul. | "Związku Młodzieży Wiejskiej ""Wici"""|
2836 | ul. |"Okulickiego ""Niedźwiadka"""          |gen. Leopolda
```

I want delete characters:

```
""
```

I try replace this characters on space.
I try to use query:

```
SELECT street_id, street_attribute REPLACE(street_name1, '""', ' '), street_name2 FROM `street`;
```

but I have error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPLACE(street_name1, '""', ' '), street_name2 FROM `street` LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. 
Can you ask for help?

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

Comment: Plus, you need to show us *exactly* how you're using your query in PHP since you did tag as such and no code to support it. As it stands, it's unclear as to how it's used and which quotes you've used to wrap that statement with.

Comment: Trying to use the query in phpmyadmin

Comment: simple, missing a comma `SELECT street_id, street_attribute, REPLACE` after your second column.

Comment: I love it when people post an answer *after* I say ^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your sql syntax, you're missing a comma :

```
SELECT street_id, street_attribute, REPLACE(street_name1, '""', ' '), street_name2 FROM `street`;
```

Comment: [Yeah, I said that 4-5 mins. prior to this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398749/replace-characters-in-row-mysql#comment58500133_35398749)

Comment: I didn't noticed that when I posted my answer because probably it been after I've entered this page, trust me I don't need to copy answers @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have double quotes `"` surrounding this query. So when you use them again in your `REPLACE` method it is closing the first double quote. You will need to escape them.

`REPLACE(street_name1, '\"\"', ' ')`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm trying to use this code REPLACE(street_name1, '\"\"', ' ') , but I have the same error.

Comment: whoever downvoted this, wasn't me. But I did see an an answer which most likely was based on a comment I left up there about it.

Comment: Finallly I export database to csv and I replaced chars in notepad++, next I import csv.